# illegal start of expression error with println expression

Tags: java

I am an absolute newbie here.  Literally just started coding today.  I keep getting an

```
"illegal start of expression error"
```

with a println expression, but for the life of me, I can't figure out why.  Here's the code...

```
public class BlockofStars {

    public static final int HEIGHT = 5;
    public static final int WIDTH = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= HEIGHT; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= WIDTH; j++){
                System.out.println(*);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need quotation marks surrounding your asterisk: `System.out.println("*");`

Comment: `System.out.println(String)`

Answer (score 4):

The * has to be a String:

```
System.out.println("*");
```